# Swift Routing enum crashes when moved to a cocoapod

Tags: swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I have recently been refactoring code into a base cocoapod for use in multiple projects. One such class is a pretty stereotypical routing enum for Alamofire. It's been working fine up until being moved into the cocoapod... which is now crashing. An example implementation:

```
public enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {

    static var baseURLString = "http://myserver.com/api"

    case Endpoint1(String, String)
    case Endpoint2(String, String, Date, Date)
    case Endpoint3(String, String)

    public var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
        var path : String! {
            switch self {
            case .Endpoint1(let id, _):
                return "/endpoint1/" + id
            case .Endpoint2(let id, _, _, _):
                return "/booking/\(id)/thing"
            case .Endpoint3(_, _):
                return "/authenticate"
            }
        }

        var parameters: [String: AnyObject] {
            switch self {
            case .Endpoint2(_, _, let startDate, let endDate):
                let params = ["startDate": startDate, "endDate" : endDate]
                return params
            default:
                let params = [String: AnyObject]()
                return params
            }
        }

        var method :  Alamofire.Method {
            switch self {
            case .Endpoint2:
                return .POST
            default:
                return .GET
            }
        }

        var body : [String : AnyObject]?{
            switch self{
            case .Endpoint3(let email, let password):
                return ["email" : "\(email)", "password" : "\(password)"]
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }

        var header : [String: String]?{
            switch self {
            case .Endpoint1(_, let token):
                return ["x-access-token" : token]
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }

        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!)

        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

        let mutable = (encoding.encode(request, parameters: parameters).0)
        mutable.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

        if let bodyParams = body{
            mutable.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            mutable.addJsonArrayToRequestBody(bodyParams)
        }

        if let headerParams = header{
            for param in headerParams{
                mutable.setValue(param.1, forHTTPHeaderField: param.0)
            }
        }

        return mutable
    }
}
```

The failure line is:

```
for param in headerParams{
```

But as it is in a development cocoapod, I can't attach a debugger to that point, nor is the error more than EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, which is less than helpful. How can I further debug what's causing the error?

Comment: Does header variable contain the expected value when you put a breakpoint before unwrapping it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the xcode debugger when using a development cocoapod, the actual error was:

let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path)

The static baseURLString had not yet been set when this method was called, leading the URL to be nil. I have seen multiple occurrences of the debugger pointing out the incorrect line when in the now shared code, not sure how to fix.